# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')

Tags: javascript, typescript, redis, express-session

so what I want to do is to create a session and store it in redis.
I followed the API from this github repository https://github.com/tj/connect-redis.

But I am getting this error in the word client: The expected type comes from property 'client' which is declared here on type 'RedisStoreOptions'.

This is the code that i used:

```js
import redis from 'redis';
import session from 'express-session';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

const app = express();

    const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
    const redisClient = redis.createClient({ legacyMode: true });
    redisClient.connect().catch(console.error);
    app.use(
        session({
          store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
          saveUninitialized: false,
          secret: "keyboard cat",
          resave: false,
        })
    )
```

The error occurs here:

```js
store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient })
```

More specifically in the word client.

Answer (score 38):

instead of

```
import redis from 'redis';
```

use

```
import * as redis from 'redis';
```

Comment: Amazing! What a simple fix.  Could you explain why this fixes it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your using TypeScript, I had this issue, did you install:

```
@types/redis
@types/connect-redis
@types/express-session
```

---

I did that and kept getting an error with the client so I uninstalled all 3 @types and noticed redis doesn't require you to declare modules so I only installed types for express-session and connect-redis

> npm i @types/connect-redis @types/express-session --save-dev

---

> yarn add @types/connect-redis
> @types/express-session -D